# How many times addTelemetryInitializer can be called?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I would like to call `addTelemetryInitializer` when initializing the application, and then when the user is logged in, I would like to add some user details to all data passed to application insights (name and other details).

Question is: **How many Telemetry initializers can be added?**

Can I call `addTelemetryInitializer` multiple times? If yes: Will they all be executed or only the latest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is quite simple:

Multiple telemetry initializers can be added to your Application Insights instance, and they are executed in order of adding them.

For more details, please see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#telemetry-initializers).